# mysql display dates as column in report

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Currently, I am displaying weekly report with only 7 columns, for a given week date range.

Date range is strictly inputted from jQuery date-picker for just a week only.

```
user   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5   |   6   |   7
---------------------------------------------------------
132    0   |   0   |   0   |   1   |   1   |   0   |   1
133    0   |   1   |   1   |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0
134    1   |   1   |   1   |   0   |   1   |   0   |   0
135    1   |   0   |   1   |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0
```

Now I want to take any date range input (not just a week range), and display the records as following:

```
user   2018-06-03   |   2018-06-04   |   2018-06-05   |   2018-06-06   |   2018-06-07   |   2018-06-08   |   2018-06-09   |   2018-06-10   |   ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
132   0            |       0        |       1        |       1        |       1        |       1        |       0        |       1        |
133   0            |       0        |       0        |       1        |       1        |       1        |       1        |       1        |
134   0            |       1        |       0        |       1        |       1        |       1        |       1        |       0        |
135   0            |       1        |       1        |       1        |       1        |       1        |       1        |       0        |
136   0            |       0        |       1        |       0        |       1        |       1        |       1        |       1        |
```

To currently display 7 days week report, here's my query script:

```
SELECT userId as user,
SUM(CASE WHEN day = 1 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '1',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 2 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '2',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 3 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '3',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 4 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '4',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 5 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '5',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 6 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '6',
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 7 THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) '7'
FROM
(
    SELECT userId, lunchStatus, DAYOFWEEK(issuedDateTime) as day 
    FROM `lunch_status` 
    WHERE DATE(issuedDateTime) BETWEEN '$week_start_date' AND '$week_end_date' 
) as a
GROUP BY user
```

How can I update my query to get what I require.

I am kind of stuck here, with whole date range thing.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). That said, I would almost certainly handle this kind of thing in application code.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL (`prepare`/`exec`) if you want to have variable column names.